# OMA DRM implementation in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, encryption, drm, oma

Can anyone help me find some drm solutions that can be implemented in asp.net mvc 3. I am developing a content manager to distribute mobile content to subscribers. What I want to do is to be able to apply the correct DRM to a file and send it out to the requesting mobile device. Is there a way I can apply DRM to files programmatically and on the fly? Please help me out